# Spring MVC email mail sending using Queue model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I have a scenario in which, I need to start a thread when the container starts and stops while the container stops. I am using Spring MVC for my application. My end-goal is to send an email when user performs a particular action. Moreover I don't want to slow the flow due to the email sending process. So what I am planning is that, I will create a queue and put the mail message in the queue whenever I need to send out a mail. A thread which is started during  the start-up will read the queue and send-out the mail. Here I am facing two problems:

1. How can I start and stop a thread when application starts/stops(For normal web application, I can make use of ServletContextListener for this.) in the case of Spring MVC?
2. In the thread, I need to call a mail service to send-out the mail. So how can I inject the service to the thread? Is it possible?

Any tip or more flexible solution is highly appreciated....

~Ragesh

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to perform mail sending in separate thread / asynchronously is use the [@Async Annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) of [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

See also

- http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-3-task-scheduling-via.html